# В чем разница между start, left, self start, safe start values for justify-items свойств?

Tags: css, grid, properties

Можете ли вы объяснить мне разницу между этими свойствами: justify-items: start justify-items: left justify-items: self start justify-items-safe start :

start это начальный уровень контейнера, то есть крайний левый угол.
left левый угол контейнера
self start аналогичен старту
safe start - нужно когда будет переполнения

Я прочитал много статей об этом, но нигде нет явных примеров, чтобы различать эти свойства.

сможете показать наглядные примеры или какую-нибудь статью, на которой есть примеры.? Я был на сайтах MDN и css-tricks, но примеров нет.